# Run-Time Error 424 Started without warning

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but none of them have helped my specific issue.
I have been teaching myself VBA and began learning Userforms from
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html

Everything worked fine and dandy until out of the blue, I received the 424 Error code when I tried to run my Userform after making some tweaks

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
StartUpUserForm.Show
End Sub
```

is the current non-working edition of this, but I have double and triple checked that the userform is called out correctly, deleted and recreated the button half a dozen times, renamed and recalled out the userform in the code and absolutely nothing helps.

The current userform is

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()

'Empty NameTextBox
NameTextBox.Value = ""

'Empty Race_Select
Race_Select.Clear
'Fill Race_Select
With Race_Select
    .AddItem "Dwarf"
    .AddItem "Elf"
    .AddItem "Gnome"
    .AddItem "Half-Elf"
    .AddItem "Half-Orc"
    .AddItem "Halfling"
    .AddItem "Human"
    .AddItem "Other"
End With

'Empty Class_Select
Class_Select.Clear
'Fill Class_Select
With Class_Select
    .AddItem "Barbarian"
    .AddItem "Bard"
    .AddItem "Cleric"
    .AddItem "Druid"
    .AddItem "Fighter"
    .AddItem "Monk"
    .AddItem "Paladin"
    .AddItem "Ranger"
    .AddItem "Rogue"
    .AddItem "Sorceror"
    .AddItem "Wizard"
End With

'Empty Attributes
Strength.Value = ""
Dexterity.Value = ""
Constitution.Value = ""
Intelligence.Value = ""
Wisdom.Value = ""
Charisma.Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub Roll_Attributes_Click()


Dim Strength As Integer
Dim Dexterity As Integer
Dim Constitution As Integer
Dim Intelligence As Integer
Dim Wisdom As Integer
Dim Charisma As Integer

'Roll Attributes
Strength = Int((18 - 3 + 1) * Rnd + 3)
Dexterity = Int((18 - 3 + 1) * Rnd + 3)
Constitution = Int((18 - 3 + 1) * Rnd + 3)
Intelligence = Int((18 - 3 + 1) * Rnd + 3)
Wisdom = Int((18 - 3 + 1) * Rnd + 3)
Charisma = Int((18 - 3 + 1) * Rnd + 3)

'Display Integer as attribute
StrengthTextBox.Text = Strength
DexterityTextBox.Text = Dexterity
ConstitutionTextBox.Text = Constitution
IntelligenceTextBox.Text = Intelligence
WisdomTextBox.Text = Wisdom
CharismaTextBox.Text = Charisma

End Sub
```

(I know it's like painting the Mona Lisa with a brick, but that's not the question here)

This issue popped up earlier today, but I was able to stave it off by renaming my userform and recalling it out with the button code. However, it came back after I renamed the attribute text boxes, and seems to be back for good.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Once you get your code to run as intended, I strongly recommend you sign up on [codereview.se], you'll learn a ton! :)

Comment: What's the text of the error message?

Comment: @TimWilliams 424 is "Object Required"

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @TimWilliams StartUpUserForm.Show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the block of code within the Initialization event that is below 'Empty Attributes.

What are these attributes? You assign to them a value as if they were objects, but they are not declared anywhere. If they are meant to be variables, declare them as such, and initialize them using `Strength = 0`.

Does this help?

EDIT: I just noticed that you are declaring the variables in the Click event for the command button. This raises an additional issue about Variable Scope. If you were to declare the variables (even if they use the same name) in the Initialize event, they will not correspond to the variables in the Click event because they are privately scoped. You should remove the references to the attributes entirely in the initialization event. Otherwise, you can look into Publicly declared variables.

Comment: Thank you, this led me to finding the issue. It turned out to be when I changed the name of the text boxes, I didn't change it in the initialize sequence. Strength.Value = 0 should have been StrengthTextBox.Value = 0, which i don't think you could have known without seeing the properties for the userform. But you just saved me a lot of aggravation. Thank you so much

Comment: @Miksoko use of `Option Explicit` would have alerted you to this error

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I'm glad I could help to steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

I assume the `StartupUserForm` exists and is named as such.

Forms are special types of *classes*, that have a *predeclaredId* - a "default instance". When you do this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
StartUpUserForm.Show
End Sub
```

You are using that *default instance*. You should be creating a *copy* of it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim frm As StartUpUserForm
    Set frm = New StartUpUserForm
    frm.Show
End Sub
```

This will make the `CommandButton21` click handler *create an object*, call the `Show` method on it, and then the object will die when the form is closed.

So why are you getting that error?

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()
```

Every class has a special `Initialize` event that runs when an instance is created - when you use a form's default instance, code in that procedure may or may not run, depending on the state of your VBA environment. That's why it's better to always create an object, so the code you write in the `Initialize` handler will always run when you intend it to.

As [@TimWilliams pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989950/run-time-error-424-started-without-warning#comment44371350_27989950), we don't know which line is blowing up with a #424 error, so it's pretty hard to help you here.

I suggest you add an error handler to help you figure out what's going on:

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    'your code here

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Stop
    Resume 'Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

What will that do for you? When an instruction blows up, the VBA editor (VBE) will have the error number and description in the *immediate pane* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to show it if it's not visible) and will highlight the line that says `Stop`, and then you can press <kbd>F8</kbd> to *step through* to the next line - VBE will highlight the instruction that says `Resume`, and then pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> again will take you straight to the line that caused the error.

Odds are, you have renamed the controls on the form, but not in the code; the `Name` property of a control is the identifier you should be using in code to refer to that control.

Your code isn't consistent between the two handlers - in the `Click` handler it seems to be `StrengthTextBox`...

```
StrengthTextBox.Text = Strength
```

...and in the `Initialize` handler it seems to be just `Strength`:

```
Strength.Value = ""
```

If the control/textbox is actually called `Strength`, then you have another problem:

```
Dim Strength As Integer
Strength = Int((18 - 3 + 1) * Rnd + 3)
```

The variables have the same name as the textboxes, and that name clash confuses VBA - it's possible VBA interprets this assignment as assigning an integer value to an object reference, which is bound to blow up.

Bottom line, verify that your control names match the identifiers you're using to refer to them in the code.